# OnAdLoaded executes, but interstitialAd.Loaded returns false

Tags: unity-game-engine, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-ads

The device that is having these weird behaviour is Huawei Matepad T8, HMS Core Version 6.3.0.326.
On this device all the other ads are working fine.

I have made a build from Unity using hms plugin V 2.1.0 on unity 2020.3.26. The logs are from the unity apk.

> [HMS] HMSAdsKitManager Loading Interstitial Ad.
>
> [HMS] HMSAdsKitManager LoadRewardedAd
>
> [HMS] HMSAdsKitManager Rewarded ad loaded!
>
> [HMS] HMSAdsKitManager OnInterstitialAdLoaded
>
> [HMS] HMSAdsKitManager OnInterstitialAdLoaded
>
> [HMS] HMSAdsKitManager Rewarded ad loaded!
>
> [HMS] AdsDemoManager ShowInterstitialAd
>
> [HMS] HMSAdsKitManager ShowInterstitialAd called
>
> [HMS] HMSAdsKitManager Interstitial Ad Still Not Loaded Yet!
>
> the logs are from hms-ads-demo-java apk
> https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-ads-demo-java.
>
> I/HiAdSDK.InterstitialAdManager(27222):  loadAd
>
> I/HiAdSDK.InterstitialAdManager(27222):  ad is invalid, content
> id:46348005
>
> I/HiAdSDK.InterstitialAdManager(27222):  onAdsLoaded, size:1
>
> I/HiAdSDK.InterstitialAdManager(27222):  loadAd
>
> I/HiAdSDK.InterstitialAdManager(27222):  ad is invalid, content
> id:46673268
>
> I/HiAdSDK.InterstitialAdManager(27222):  onAdsLoaded, size:1

I have test these 2 apk's on a different device Huawei P40 lite, and everithing was working fine. I have to mention that these two devices (huawei mate T8 and P40 lite) are real devices.
The Country/Region Is not US.

Comment: hi@Cosmin Olaru, please provide your complete log, so that we can analyse this issue. You could get the complete log from the following steps.1. Run the following command to connect to the device:  `adb logcat –v time > D:\hwads.log`
2. Reproduce the issue.3. Press Ctrl+C to complete log capture.

Comment: hi @shirley, I've uploaded the log file to WeTransfer, you can download the file from here [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/30257cf71d657f48140efdf0f7bc297320220126073029/838abb) .The log file is from my unity apk, the apk has only the hms plugin V 2.1.0.

Comment: According to the [log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFofM.png), looks like the timing's a little off. It should be 01-26. could you mind try correcting the time on your phone and try again?

Comment: hi, it looks like the timing correction solved my problem. But I have a lot of users that are complaining about these problem, and I cannot force the users to change their timing. What can we do to solve these bug?

Comment: sorry but there's no way to solve it. Ad tasks are closely related to time, if a future time is send, at this time in the future whether advertisers place ads, is uncertain.